# WPF Datagrid Combobox binding to each other within the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

How to get a WPF datagrid combobox to bind within the datagrid elements.

For example: I have a collection of People => Name, Age and Sex.

- Foo, 18, Male
- Boo, 21, Male
- FooBoo, 30, Female

Now inside the datagrid i have a combobox (DataGridComboBoxColumn) with the collection of the names only (Foo, Boo, FooBoo) ItemsSoure and two DataGridTextBoxColumn. The Datagrid is binded to a ObservableCollection or DataTable. Now when the user select a name. The age and sex shows (bind) in the two DataGridTextBoxColumn and is added to the DataTable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `ComboBox` needs to be defined something like:

```
<ComboBox Name="PeopleCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

along with anything else that it needs (and the correct binding for `ItemsSource`). This way it "contains" the entire Person class but only displays the name.
Now, you can just define your `TextBox`es like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=PeopleCombo, Path=SelectedItem.Sex}" />
```

I do not understand what you want as far as adding it to the DataTable source, though.

Also, this would probably be a lot easier with an MVVM pattern, where you have a ViewModel class with a "SelectedPerson" property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm looking to have the same as what you have said in a Datagrid not in a window.